# Почему я не могу передать значения словаря data в Aiogram FSM в другой хендлер?

Tags: python, aiogram

```
    class FsmHand(StatesGroup):
    Inp = State()
    Out = State()
    St = State()

@dp.message_handler(commands=['send'])
async def start(message: types.Message):
    if (message.from_user.id == 111111):
        await message.answer("ID")
        await FsmHand.Inp.set()


async def inp(message: types.Message,state: FSMContext):
    async with state.proxy() as data:
        data["Inp"] = message.text
    await FsmHand.next()
    await message.answer("Сумма")

async def out(message: types.Message, state: FSMContext):
    async with state.proxy() as data:
        data["Out"] = message.text

    z = data.get("Inp")
    x = data.get("Out")
    await message.answer(f"{z},{x}")#Тут я вижу введенные значения

    await bot.send_message(z,"бла бла")
    


@dp.callback_query_handler(text="yes")
async def test_call(callback_query: types.CallbackQuery,state: FSMContext):
    async with state.proxy() as data: #Снова открываю 
        x = data.get("Out")
        z = data.get("Inp")
        print(z,x) # тут значения уже None - куда они пропадают?
        await callback_query.message.answer(f"{z},{x}блабла")
    await state.finish()
```

Comment: Значит вы где-то по ходу удалили значения или очистили словарь через await state.finish()

Comment: Я дал развернутый ответ с примером кода в другом вашем вопросе
https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1423660/Как-передать-значение-из-словаря-fsm-в-хендлер-инлаин-кнопки