# Как передать значение из словаря FSM в хендлер инлаин кнопки

Tags: python, aiogram

Я отравляю число в состояние и записываю его в словарь
другой пользователь получает текст с инлаин кнопкой и по ее нажатию получаем мое число.
Я уже не знаю что делать
когда открываю словарь в хенлере кнопки - он пустой
Можете накалякать мне кусок кода ,а то я уже все перепробовал.

```
class FsmHand(StatesGroup):
    Inp = State()

dp.message_handler(commands=['send'])
async def start(message: types.Message):
    if (message.from_user.id == 1111111):
        await message.answer("ID")
        await FsmHand.Inp.set()

async def inp(message: types.Message,state: FSMContext):
    async with state.proxy() as data:
        data["Inp"] = message.text
        
dp.callback_query_handler(text="yes")
async def test_call(callback_query: types.CallbackQuery,state: FSMContext):
    async with state.proxy() as data:
        print(data) #ДАТА ПУСТАЯ
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вопрос поставлен не корректно но я попробую дать на него ответ.
Как я понял не из описания а из представленного кода что вам нужно чтобы state_data попал в callback_query_handler

Рассмотрю пример составления сообщения для некого юзера код написан в теории мб где ошибки по синтаксису но вроде все гуд
state='*' Пускает в хэндер любой стейт!

```
class State_1(StatesGroup):
    input_user = State() # Ввод юзера
    input_message = State() # Ввод сообщения


@dp.message_handler(commands=['send_message_for_user'])
async def send_message_for(message: types.Message):
    reply_markup = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()  # Создаем клавиатуру
    reply_markup.add(types.InlineKeyboardButton(text=f'Отменить', callback_data=f'cancel_state'))  # Добавляем кнопку
    await message.answer("Укажите chat id получателя", reply_markup=reply_markup)  # Отправляем сообщение
    await State_1.input_user.set()


@dp.message_handler(state=State_1.input_user)
async def send_message_for_input_user(message: types.Message, state: FSMContext):
    try:
        await state.set_data({'chat_id': int(message.text)})
        reply_markup = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()  # Создаем клавиатуру
        reply_markup.add(types.InlineKeyboardButton(text=f'Отменить', callback_data=f'cancel_state'))  # Добавляем кнопку
        await message.answer(f'Введите сообщение для: {message.text}', reply_markup=reply_markup)
        await State_1.input_message.set()
    except: await message.delete() # Пользователь отправил не число удаляем его ошибку и ждем повтора


@dp.message_handler(state=State_1.input_message)
async def send_message_for_input_message(message: types.Message, state: FSMContext):
    try:
        await state.update_data({'message': message.text})
        reply_markup = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()  # Создаем клавиатуру
        reply_markup.add(types.InlineKeyboardButton(text=f'Отменить', callback_data=f'cancel_state'),
                     types.InlineKeyboardButton(text=f'Отправить', callback_data=f'send_message_for'))  # Добавляем кнопку
        await message.answer(f'{message.text}', reply_markup=reply_markup)

    except:
        await message.delete()  # Пользователь отправил не число удаляем его ошибку и ждем повтора


@dp.callback_query_handler(state=State_1)
async def test_call(callback_query: types.CallbackQuery, state: FSMContext):
    state_data = await state.get_data()
    if callback_query.data == 'cancel_state':
        await state.reset_state()
        await callback_query.answer(f'Отмена')
    elif callback_query.data == 'send_message_for':
        await bot.send_message(state_data['chat_id'], state_data['message'])
        await callback_query.message.answer(f'Сообщение успешно отправлено')
```

Comment: Это не решило мою проблему. Все работает но мне нудно чтобы когда человек получал мое сообщение + моя инлаин клавиатура, по нажатию кнопки он получал текс с этим же мои сообщением

Comment: `@dp.callback_query_handler(text="yes")
async def test_call(callback_query: types.CallbackQuery,state: FSMContext):
    state_data = await state.get_data()
    print(state_data)
    await callback_query.message.answer(f"""Сделка № 9646\nСумма сделки: {state_data['message']} RUB`(тут state_data уже пустая)

Comment: Я сделал как хотел через добавления в лист-бд, но если сможете помочь с моей проблемой без использования сторонних бд было бы супер